# What is the purpose of Regex.Escape?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have a  code like below where 'QualifiedInstanceFilter' is  Accessor for the qualified instance filter. Can anybody tell me what logic happening in the line m_afc.QualifiedInstanceFilter = "^(" + Regex.Escape(this.Identifier) + ")$";
this is full code

```
 public override string Identifier
      {
         get
         {
 return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}",
                 Owner.Class,
                 IDSeparator,
                 ManagedClass.Name, IDClassNameSeparator, Instance);

private AlertFilter m_afc = new AlertFilter("", "", true, "", "", "");

    m_afc.QualifiedInstanceFilter = "^(" + Regex.Escape(this.Identifier) + ")$";
```

Comment: Have you tried to look at MSDN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Regex.Escape` is there to "escape" a string that may contain characters that have special meaning in a Regex. For example (a simple example):

Let's say I wanted to search a string based on user input. One would assume I could write a regex like `".*" + UserInput + ".*"`. The problem with this is what if the user searched for "$money"? The `$` has special meaning in Regex, thus resuling in this Regex: `.*$money.` - which is incorrect.

If we used `Regex.Escape` before that, then the `$` character would be escaped to avoid that behavior.

You can learn more about it from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx),

> Escapes a minimal set of characters `(\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,.`,
>   `#`, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes. This
>   instructs the regular expression engine to interpret these characters
>   literally rather than as metacharacters.

In your code, it is setting a concatenated string equal to `m_afc.QualifiedInstanceFilter` and "escaping" whatever is in `this.Identifier`. If there are any special characters, then they are pre-pended with a `\` and treated as non-metacharacters.

Comment: In your list the leading parenthesis should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The strings that together make up an `Identifier` are arbitrary strings - they could conceivably include such characters as `[` `]` `*` `\` and all the other characters that have special meanings within regular expressions. However, the desired effect of `QualifiedInstanceFilter` is to *literally match* the `Identifier`, so if we just said

```
m_afc.QualifiedInstanceFilter = "^(" + this.Identifier + ")$";
```

we *might* end up with a value such as `^(()$(${P${}$*${$}{$)$`, which would confuse the regex engine immensely. So we use `Regex.Escape` to say: "I want to use this string in a regular expression, but I want characters that are normally special to regex to NOT have their special meaning". The regex engine will then escape special characters (by prepending a `\`), so that when we create a regular epxression by concatentation, the only regex-special characters in it are the ones we put there - the initial `^(` and the final `)$`.

Answer (score 1):

To put it a bit more simply than the other answers:

What do you do if you want to match on a character which is a special character in Regex, e.g. a period "."?  You put a backslash in front of it, i.e. you *escape* it.

`Regex.Escape` does this for any string you pass it, so it can escape stuff you don't know at compile time.  One example would be including user-specified strings in the regex, which may contain special characters.